# Network NIC QCA8171 not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, atheros

I have a Asrock BM-ITX motherboard with qualcom network chip on it QCA8171. It gets recognized by ubuntu but it is not able to work no network connection can be established.

`lshw`:

```
*-network DISABLED,
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: p2p1
       version: 10
       serial: d0:50:99:3f:17:44
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 memory:f0400000-f043ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue.
Due to the fact that i swapped my motherboard which has a different networkchip causes that the **logical name** for network changed from **eth0** to **p2p1**.
After changing eth0 to p2p1 in the file **/etc/network/interfaces** everything works fine.